# Why does my Android app stops, when I move it to the background?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application and I have the following code lines:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }

    [... SOME MORE CODE ...]

}
```

When I test it on the emulator, it works perfectly and it closes the app and opens it at the some point as before. But when I load the APK on a real device, it always stops the application and starts it new, when I open it again. With the loading screen.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's happening. Is it crashing? Or is it simply restarting when it should resume?

Comment: As you are saying that your app getting crashed when it go to background, for this you should attach your device to eclipse and debug what cause while your app go to background

Comment: What kind of real device is it ? Have your tried different devices ?

Comment: This is a device specific behavior. Try it on some other device it will work.

Comment: But I want that it works on all devices. This problem occurs on the most used Android tablet and on the HTC One.

Comment: yes i know, I first faced this problem in samsung galaxy tab 2.
Your answer is given her, for how to kind of question, post a new question.

Comment: No, it doesn't crash, it only starts the application from the beginning. with my loading screen an the start activity. is is on the most used Android tablet and on the HTC One.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the state of the activity ? the solution is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)